# Which file loads (includes) javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have a website with lot of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) files loaded, it's [joomla](/questions/tagged/joomla) site, and there a lot's of conflicts between them. As components, modules, plugins, joomla, framework loads `js` files. So my question is, is there a tool, that I could use to check which file (`.php`, `.html`...) loaded the js file that gives me problem?

P.S. I'm familiar with firebug, but didn't find anything there that could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct access to the files and you are running a Linux server you could use `grep -ri "name/of/script.js"` to find the conflicting files. Otherwise: just download all the files in the Joomla directory and grep them locally.

Comment: thanks for answering. I didn't mentioned that I used method you mentioned, downloaded entire site and search for script name in files. Beside it can be time consuming (downloading a huge website), the primary problem is that many cases, e.g. php file/function that calls the problematic js, the name of the file is passed to it as variable, and in the form of variable passed many times deep through framework structure. So my search just returns e.g. a config file with script paths, or worst case nothing as the paths are stored in DB.

Comment: I'm afraid that there doesn't seem to be another option, since Joomla does not trace any modules, plugins or components loading script files as far as I know. And it's even harder to find them because not every developer uses the methods Joomla provides to inject scripts. I've seen many extensions loading js in plain HTML. However to speed up the search for the files and skip downloading them you could use some php code like `passthru('grep -ri "script.js" .');`
`\`grep -ri "script.js" .\`` to search for the files. But it does not work on some servers.